# Send lighthouse metrics using NodeJS to Graphite

Tags: node.js, metrics, graphite, lighthouse, graphite-carbon

I am trying to send some lighthouse reports to Graphite. I have come across this **NodeJS** project [Github lighthouse Project](https://github.com/aykut-rocks/lighthouse-to-graphite) which generates the lighthouse reports and send to graphite.

So I've done few things -

1. Spun up a graphite container on one my of EC2 instance using this image - https://hub.docker.com/r/graphiteapp/graphite-statsd/
2. Modified index.js with the relevant details of Graphite to push the data from lighthouse to my graphite container.
3. Running `node index.js` also works fine without any errors BUT I am not able to see any data in Graphite web UI.

These are the things which we need to configure in index.js -

```
const graphitePort = '8080'; // my container is exposed to port 8080
const graphiteHost = '<mypublicip of EC2>'; // e.g. 'carbon.hostedgraphite.com'
**const graphitePath = '<<No Idea on this >>'; // e.g. 'lighthouse.performance' or 'your-api-key'**
const url = 'https://github.com/';
```

I have no idea what the graphitePath is here and how to get it. Please if someone can advice on this that would be immensely helpful

Comment: Are you able to send data to Graphite (without using lighthouse)? Just to check if your Graphite server is working properly

Comment: Hi @SauravKumar yes I am able to send the data using sitespeed.io container. I can see data in both Graphite and Grafana. Used this to spin up containers - https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/sitespeed.io/performance-dashboard/ I am trying to send the data from my nodejs project to the same container on port 2003 but it's not reflecting. I also don't get any errors while running the nodejs project so not sure what could be wrong

Comment: UPDATE - I am able to send the data directly using the lighthouse command as well ```lighthouse-graphite https://www.stackoverflow.com --run=3 --graphite-host=myhost --graphite-prefix=lighthouse.example_com``` and can see the data getting reflected in Graphite. It's just that when I use this project with NodeJS then it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong here. Let me know if anyone has any thoughts